# How does protobuf-net achieve respectable performance?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I want to understand why [the protocol buffers solution for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) developed by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) is as fast as it is.

I can understand how the original Google solution achieved its performance: it pre-generates optimized code for object serialization; I've written some serialization by hand and know that it is possible to write pretty fast code this way if you avoid reflection. But Marc's library is a runtime solution that uses attributes and doesn't produce any generated code. So how does it work ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the source? Or even asking Mark directly?

Comment: I tried and even have some ideas but if some one can give quick answer it would be nice

Comment: I'll happily talk about this for hours ;-p But it will have to wait until I finish work...

Comment: Will be waiting for the evening then.

Comment: What do you mean is not a real question? it's very real, translation for those that didn't understood the question : "What coding techniques algorithms or technologies used, make protobuf-net allot faster than typical serialization?" is this not a real question?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

protobuf-net uses a strategy pattern; as needed (once only per type) it uses reflection to look at the types, and builds a set of serializers (based on a common interface) that it can use to serialize and deserialize - so *when in use* it is just stepping through the known set of serializers.

*Inside* that, it tries to make sensible use of reflection when talking to members; it uses `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to talk to properties, and `DynamicMethod` (and custom IL) to talk to fields (when possible; it depends on the target framework). This means that it is always talking to *known* delegate types, rather than just `DynamicInvoke` (which is very slow).

Without going mad, the code does have some optimisations (arguably at the expense of readability) in terms of:

- local `byte[]` buffering (of the input/output streams)
- using fixed-size arrays (rather than lists etc); perhaps too much
- using generics to avoid boxing
- numerous tweaks/twiddles/etc around the binary processing loops

In hindsight, I think I made a mistake on the generics point; the complexity meant that forcing generics into the system [bent it out of shape in a few places](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/05/generics-and-when-not-to.html), and actively causes some major problems (for complex models) [on compact framework](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/compact-framework-woes-revisted.html).

I have some designs (in my head only) to refactor this using *non*-generic interfaces, and to instead (for suitable frameworks) make more use of `ILGenerator` (my first choice would have been `Expression`, but that forces a higher framework version). The problem, however, is that this is going to take a considerable amount of time to get working, and until very recently [I've been pretty swamped](http://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/5584270993).

Recently I've managed to [start spending some time on protobuf-net again](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/compact-framework-woes-revisted.html), so hopefully I'll clear my backlog of requests etc and get started on that soon. It is also my intention to get it working with models *other* than reflection (i.e. describing the wire mapping separately).

---

> and doesn't produce any generated code

I should also clarify that there are two (optional) codegen routes if you want to use generated code; protogen.exe, or the [VS add-in](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/07/protobuf-net-now-with-added-orcas.html), allow code generation from a .proto file. But this is not *needed* - it is useful mainly if you have an existing .proto file, or intent to interoperate with another language (C++ etc) for contract-first development.

Answer (score -2):

Its performance very good!

You can see a comprehensive comparison between different formats including protobuf done by me-
http://maxondev.com/serialization-performance-comparison-c-net-formats-frameworks-xmldatacontractserializer-xmlserializer-binaryformatter-json-newtonsoft-servicestack-text/

This comparison includes large and small data samples and different formats.

One of the tests in my post-
[image]

Comment: The question was about how the performance was accomplished, not how performant it is.